# Connection of iPhone devices

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone programming. I want to connect one iphone devices to another iphone device or simulator. Can anyone has idea how to figure out this problem??

Comment: Sure you can: turn on personal hotspot on one, and look for wi-fi hotspots, and connect.  ... But of course, that's not the kind of connection you're looking for.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Study Bonjour and GameKit and if you want to go deeper CFNetworks. Here is a Bonjour tutorial

http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/

GameKit Programming Guide:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Game Kit tutorial:
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502/0/page/1

All the  best :)